# react material ui populate table from API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Material ui table accept data in this format.

```
 rows: [
      createData(1, "dashboard", "details"),
      createData(2, "product", "product details"),
    ].sort((a, b) => (a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1))
```

And the response from API that I store in state is like

```
rows: Array(2)
 0: {id: 1, category_name: "dashboard", category_details: "details"}
 1: {id: 2, category_name: "product", category_details: "product details"}
 length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So how to assign the response from json array to material ui table in react?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like below

```
 const dataRows = [];
 this.state.rows.forEach((item, i) => {
    dataRows.push(createData(item.id, item.category_name, item.category_details));
 });
```

console.log(“rows”, dataRows);

// above console log will print

```
  [
  createData(1, "dashboard", "details"),
  createData(2, "product", "product details"),
 ]
```

Just pass dataRows to material-UI table